Can this code being used as singleton alternative code?
I have write the small piece of code below.
Can it be used as the singleton design pattern or do you see any drawbacks?
If so, could you tell me why you would advise me against it?
I've tested it in a multithreaded environment and it seems to work fine.
Then you can initialize the object as you want.
Thanks
Marco
#include <iostream>
#include <syncstream>
#include <memory>

class SSingleton
{
    struct Singleton
    {
        Singleton ();

        void doSomething (int &, int&, int &); 
    };

    std::weak_ptr<Singleton> instance;
public:
    SSingleton();
    
    void doSomething (int &, int&, int &);
};

SSingleton::Singleton::Singleton ()
{
    std::osyncstream syncStream(std::cout);
    syncStream << "Singleton created only once" << std::endl;
}
    
void SSingleton::Singleton::doSomething (int &a, int &b, int &c) 
{
    std::osyncstream syncStream(std::cout);
    syncStream << "doSomething execution " << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << std::endl;
}
    
SSingleton::SSingleton ()
{
    static std::shared_ptr<Singleton> instance(new Singleton());

    if (instance.get() != nullptr)                                                                      
        this->instance = std::static_pointer_cast<Singleton>(instance);
}
   
void SSingleton::doSomething (int &a, int &b, int &c) 
{
    if (auto p = this->instance.lock())
        p->doSomething (a, b, c);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<SSingleton> myst (new SSingleton());

    int a = 70, b = 80, c = 90;
    myst->doSomething(a, b, c); 

    return 0;
}



How is this better than a simple static Singleton instance;? It's automatically thread-safe.

If you are going to go down the Singleton route (which is not recommended by many), why not use a Meyer's singleton?  As mentioned by @HolyBlackCat, your problem has already been solved, and much more easily.

It's seems like a complicated mix of shared_ptr and weak_ptr -- I suppose you want your singleton to be destructed when nobody is using it? But even that probably doesn't work -- like you forgot to check for the failure of lock(), and if my theory is correct, there wouldn't even be a weak_ptr there, because you would use shared_ptr to keep track of active instances, not weak_ptr... In most cases, I just put my singletons as a static into a static get() call...

HI Christian Stieber
I corrected failure of lock section.

For anything bigger then a toy project (or maybe an embedded one) I would say try a design without singletons at all. Give your current singleton an abstract baseclass, create an instance of a concrete class in your main and use dependency injection to inject this instance into code that needs access to it. Singletons (like global variables) have a tendency to glue distant parts of the code together making unit testing and refactoring almost impossible in the long run.

And I totally agree with @PaulMcKenzie, if you're going to use a "singleton" use the meyer's singleton pattern  Singleton& get_instance() { static Singleton instance; return instance; } It is simple, it's initialization is even threadsafe and the instance of the Singleton will be destructed at termination of your program.

If two threads create SSingleton instance, there's a data race in the constructor on st_instance between the assignment st_instance = instance and the check if (st_instance == nullptr). Also a race on instance, between instance.unique() and instance.reset()

Hi HolyBlackCat for thread-safe I meant to say: Thread-safe the code inside the function "do something" using the mutex "mtx_singleton". Then I preferred to use smarts pointer for memory management.

Hi PaulMcKenzie I preferred instantiate object with a constructor.

if (st_instance == nullptr) -- This is a data race.  What if thread 1 sees that st_instance is nullptr, and then thread 2 comes in and also sees st_instance is nullptr?  You now have two threads in the same initialization code, thus your singleton is no longer a singleton.

@Curiosity I've tested it in a multithreaded environment and it seems to work fine -- I will be honest with you.  You cannot determine if it is ok in a MT environment by simply running the code -- it doesn't work this way.  You must know if it is ok in a MT environment by looking at the code and understanding what may or may not occur.  There is a Iot of MT code running now that have data races, and those errors may not occur for possibly months or even years.  It is when those rare times the error occurs does the programmer look more carefully and say "yes, that was coded incorrectly"

Hi Igor Tandetnik. The condition st_instance == nullptr only serves to avoid to perform unnecessarily the same code once the memory is allocated  and to tell you the truth I didn't done it thinking as a thread-safe solution. About the race condition between instance.unique() and instance.reset() I understand what you mean to say and I will try another code next days. What do you think if instance.reset() waits until st_instance no longer points to nullptr?

Hi Paul McKenzie I've also written ... work fine ... using the "mtx_singleton" mutex inside the "doSomething" function. I didn't write that I performed a multithreading initialization. But about race conditions I replied Igor Tandetnik. Please tell me also what do you think.

@PaulMcKenzie I've made some little changes at the constructor "SSingleton::SSingleton ()". Do you see any race condition? Thanks

@IgorTandetnik I've made some little changes at the constructor "SSingleton::SSingleton ()". Do you see any race condition? Thanks

Hi @ChristianStieber about your question: "I suppose you want your singleton to be destructed when nobody is using it?" To tell you the true no, I just want to be destructed at the end of program.

Many people recommend to use Meyer's singleton for its simplicity. But it doesn't work correctly with unit tests, like most of implementations. On my implementation of singleton (which is relatively complex), all singletons (and all threads) are automatically destroyed at end of each test case, to ensure test atomicity and detection of memory leaks.

There's still a race between if (st_instance.get() == nullptr) and st_instance = instance;. Taking a step back, what you have now is a Meyers singleton with pointless layers of shared_ptr and weak_ptr on top. static std::shared_ptr<Singleton> instance(new Singleton()); is where all the interesting stuff happens; the rest is busywork. E.g. st_instance doesn't appear to serve any useful purpose whatsoever.

Hi @IgorTandetnik. I used st_instance because in the main function I can initialize a "singleton" object like "std::shared_ptr myst (new SSingleton());" therefore like a normal initialization (to do that the other methods didn't work for me but maybe I had wrong somewhere). Could you give me a pratical example of the race condition in the part of code that you pointed?

Well, two threads enter SSingleton constructor at about the same time. The first one executes st_instance = instance and at the same time, the second checks st_instance.get() == nullptr. This exhibits undefined behavior - the same object is being accessed and modified from two threads with no synchronization.

Hi @IgorTandetnik (first of all thanks for your patience). Let me to understand. The problem is the eventually simultaneous execution of "st_instance = instance" with two theads? Assuming instance value is always the same (with already considered some exceptions); do you mean to say that this execution ("st_instance = instance") it's not thread-safe when st_instance and instance are shared_ptr?

cppreference.com says: All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same instance of shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the std::atomic<shared_ptr> can be used to prevent the data race.

Two st_instance = instance do cause a data race. But even before you get there, an assignment st_instance = instance and an access st_instance.get() alreay exhibit a data race. It's right there in the passage you quote: "If multiple threads of execution access the same instance of shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur." st_instance is the same instance  being accessed, operator= is the non-const member function.

Hi @IgorTandetnik due to the race condition in st_instance = instance I rewrote my code. Could it be ok now? Thanks Marco

Looks OK to me now. Even too thread-safe: you don't need a lock around this->instance = std::static_pointer_cast<Singleton>(instance); The static instance is only read, never written; and this->instance is only possibly accessible by a single thread at this point; the thread that constructs this SSingleton object. And since it's the only remaining use of mtx_singleton, turns out you don't need the mutex at all. Apart from all that, I still don't understand why you need shared_ptr or weak_ptr to Singleton (single S), and still maintain that you can very well do without.

Hi @IgorTandetnik To tell you the truth I didn't intend to use mutexes to copy static values but the fear of making another mistake took over. I'm interested in using a shared pointer as an instance to allow the automatic freeing of memory exclusively at the end of the program. I made the big mistake of persisting in thinking the use of st_instance pointer was indispensable (the result of poorly thought-out choices) and above all thread-safe...

I want to apologize and at the same time thank all those who in my interest were trying to make me understand while I committed the sin of presumption.

Plain old static Singleton instance; would provide thread-safe initialization, as well as automatically destroy instance at the end of the program. Your program already relies on this property static local variables (sometimes referred to as "magic statics"); shared_ptr neither helps nor hurts.

Hi @IgorTandetnik But about the 'automatic destroying' I tried running this code 'int main() { static int * var = new int (5); return 0; }' and valgrind returned me 'memory leak'.

In your example, it's the int* pointer being automatically destroyed, not the int it's pointing to. What I'm suggesting is more like static int var = 5; - no pointers or heap allocation anywhere. Perhaps this example might prove illuminating.

Hi @IgorTandetnik everything very clear (and simple) without heap allocation. I have never used this solution before.

Well, this is what everyone was telling you from the start. This pattern is known as Meyers' Singleton (after Scott Meyers, author of a series of popular books on C++, who proposed it in one of those books).

@IgorTandetnik I agree. But as already said I wanted to create an object of class in main function without "restrictions". However, I don't want to be misunderstood because I would gladly read the book that was suggested to me precisely because I love reading C and C++ programming books. But believe me (without wanting to go into specifics) unfortunately I don't have the opportunity to purchase it at the moment.
